# wordpress custom field get value from multi array

Tags: wordpress

My custom field return this below result. 
in this code state : "wa"
need to compere for post filter using query object. Help me to solve this.

```
a:33:{s:7:"address";s:45:"Tennyson Rd, Gladesville, NSW, Australia 2111";s:11:"gpsLatitude";s:10:"-33.825443";s:12:"gpsLongitude";s:18:"151.11965039999995";s:18:"streetViewLatitude";s:10:"-33.825443";s:19:"streetViewLongitude";s:18:"151.11965039999995";s:17:"streetViewHeading";s:1:"0";s:15:"streetViewPitch";s:1:"0";s:14:"streetViewZoom";s:18:"1.0000000000000002";s:9:"telephone";s:12:"0402 029 193";s:8:"facebook";s:33:"https://www.facebook.com/paintix/";s:7:"twitter";s:0:"";s:8:"linkedin";s:0:"";s:10:"membership";a:1:{s:3:"hia";s:3:"hia";}s:5:"state";s:2:"wa";s:4:"area";s:21:"ADELAIDE METROPOLITAN";s:6:"region";s:11:"western nsw";s:8:"category";s:24:"AIRCONDITIONING MECHANIC";s:12:"contact_name";s:12:"Oren Rahimi ";s:5:"email";s:17:"iq@paintix.com.au";s:3:"abn";s:14:"97 542 134 611";s:14:"licence_number";s:16:"44868S / 205210C";s:7:"insured";s:1:"1";s:19:"insured_expiry_date";s:0:"";s:17:"emailContactOwner";a:1:{s:6:"enable";s:6:"enable";}s:3:"web";s:22:"http://paintix.com.au/";s:11:"hoursMonday";s:0:"";s:12:"hoursTuesday";s:0:"";s:14:"hoursWednesday";s:0:"";s:13:"hoursThursday";s:0:"";s:11:"hoursFriday";s:0:"";s:13:"hoursSaturday";s:0:"";s:11:"hoursSunday";s:0:"";s:18:"alternativeContent";s:0:"";}
```